# Ubuntu-SDK installation

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-sdk

So I have a clean Ubuntu 64bit 12.04 VM ... please explain why the installation fails following simple instructions on the Ubuntu site? (http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/). As a former C# developer I would like to show my colleagues how easy this stuff is, but it just does not seem mature enough if you need to perform contortions to install the SDK. Or am I doing something wrong?

For those interested the issues I get are ones of unmet dependencies because of conflicting version of a library (see below). But to be honest I am more frustrated that the development environment does not work out of the bag, like the python or Microsoft development environments.

```
sudo apt-get install  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin : Depends: 
qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin (>= 1.1.0) 
but 1.0.0bzr25precise0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Update:**
I have already been through all the similar questions in this site and none of them address this issue. I have tried even the detailed ones like this: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I am trying this on a clean 12.04 LTS 64bit VM, so there should be no conflicts.

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: I've already been through every question on here in painstaking detail over the last week. None of them resolve the issue, including this one.

Comment: Well it seems like someone has marked this as a duplicate so I will give up on this site. Anyone else who is interested I have raised a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-qtcreator-plugins/+bug/1281814